Probably a 90s/or early 2000's movie with a female alien/mutant burnt alive
I really don't remember much about this movie because I saw it about 12-13 years ago when I was a kid sitting in a bar with my father who was drinking beer.

This is a Hollywood movie (pretty sure) and is some kind of alien, mutant or vampire movie.
The actress is herself an alien/mutant or I think she becomes one.
The actor is in love with her.
In the end she is put in a cell or a room where she is burnt alive. And the actor who was sad because her love was going to be killed goes into that room so that he can die with her. And they start kissing each other with flames rising and the movie ends. 

That's it. I have been struggling to find it for years.

Could it be that you're thinking of Return of the Living Dead 3 (1993), which Wikipedia describes as a "romantic-horror film". 

In it, Curt tries to revive his dead girlfriend Julie by turning her into a zombie, using the 2-4-5 Trioxin gas his father was experimenting with. 
As Julie gets a craving for human flesh, she tries to keep herself from giving in by hurting herself, for instance by embedding shards of glass under her skin and by driving nails and other pieces of metal through various parts of her body, which you can see in the image.
In the end,

When all of the zombies are captured, Curt realizes Julie is going to be used as a weapon and goes into a rage, freeing the zombies which then kill the soldiers. In the commotion the base is set on fire and Curt is bitten by a zombie. Curt's father tries to get Curt to leave but he realizes that by doing this he would be abandoning Julie, and he knows that he is infected. So, Curt and Julie go to the furnace to die together. Julie asks where they are, Curt says "where we belong" they kiss one last time and then burn.
Wikipedia

